# How do I add in a comma between numbers in excel?

Tags: excel, formatting, number-formatting, custom-formatting

I have a column with multiple numbers which are actually prices but the commas do not show up in the numbers so it shows up like it example 1. I need to add in commas in the numbers and add a euro sign for every number like in example 2.

[Example situation now (example 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E57M7.png)

[What I want for every column (example 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fmSB.png)

I have tried using custom number formats but it doesn't seem to support what I want to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your cells and use:

```
€ 0","00;€ -0","00;€ 0","00
```

As a custom format.

[image]

---

For better understanding, here a [link](https://www.exceltactics.com/definitive-guide-custom-number-formats-excel/) to explain the pattern and below image in more detail.

[image]

So the used custom format has now got a format for both *Postive* numeric values, for *negative* numeric values **and** for *zero* numeric values seperated through the semi-colon.

Comment: Bedankt, het is opgelost :)